# why i can't create @IBOutlet for UIImageView in a custom cell

Tags: swift, xcode

Tried in the same project in another TableView with TabelViewCell, also an error. In another project there is no such error.
[image]

Comment: Are you using the same property name in the other project?  Pretty sure that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'are trying to create a property that exists in the objective-c bridged `UITableViewCell` class ( which is deprecated )

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623213-image?language=objc

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
```

here are some of the properties that you can't override

> textLabel
>
> detailTextLabel
>
> imageView
>
> image

Comment: thank. I had a thought about it. I tried to change the name on imageView... But did not get))